# Math subscript inside ExplSyntax switches

Tags: expl3, subscripts, xparse

I'd tried to rewrite @egreg answer given in this [Reusing of DeclarePairedDelimiter in a foreach manner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457726/reusing-of-declarepaireddelimiter-in-a-foreach-manner) thread to solve another 'code reuse' issue, but I've got some problem with math subscript between ExplSyntax switches I believe.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \serafiel_definedelimiters:NN
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand #1 {E{_^}{{a+}{\alpha}}m}
   {
    \mathrm{#2}
    \c_math_subscript_token{##1}
    \c_math_superscript_token{##2}
    ##3
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \serafiel_definedelimiters:NN { cN }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definedelimiters}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \serafiel_definedelimiters:cN ##1 ##1
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definedelimiters{ D, I }

\begin{document}
\[
 \I x(t) \qquad \D x(t)
\]
\[
 \I_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t) \qquad \D_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t)
\]
\end{document}
```

I did it in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
 {
  \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{E{_^}{{a+}{\alpha}}m}
   {
    \mathrm{#1}_{##1}^{##2}##3
   }
 }

\test{I}
\test{D}

\begin{document}
\[
 \I x(t) \qquad \D x(t)
\]
\[
 \I_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t) \qquad \D_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t)
\]
\end{document}
```

but I wonder why my rewritten code do not work as I expected.

Comment: Try using `\sb` in place of the underscore for subscripts. (There is also `\sp` for superscript, should you need it.) Oh wait, you seem to be using an underscore to delimit an argument? Due to catcode changes, that is trickier. (I don't know ExplSyntax; it's on my list of things to learn.)

Comment: the xparse NewDocumentCommand interface is intended to be the top level document syntax declaration, not embedded in expl3 code which is the lower level implementation layer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know that. I should use NewDocumentCommand to make command which makes another command and use it twice. But what if I want to use this many times, because I want to more than two new commands which share almost the same implementation? Let's consider dumb example when I'd like to use `\NewDocumendCommand\<x>{}{\mathbb{<x>}}` for x = N, Z, Q, R, C. It's not so much, but if I want to do the same kind of work for large amount of new commands wchich share implementation in this manner? I dream about some kind of 'pre-processor' which can do it for me in a foreach loop style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit suboptimal, but hey, it works!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \serafiel_definedelimiters:NN
 {
  \use:x
   {
    \NewDocumentCommand #1
     {E{\char_generate:nn{`_}{8}^}{\exp_not:n{{a+}{\alpha}}}m}
   }
   {
    \mathrm{#2}
    \c_math_subscript_token{##1}
    \c_math_superscript_token{##2}
    ##3
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \serafiel_definedelimiters:NN { cN }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definedelimiters}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \serafiel_definedelimiters:cN ##1 ##1
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\definedelimiters{ D, I }

\begin{document}
\[
 \I x(t) \qquad \D x(t)
\]
\[
 \I_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t) \qquad \D_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t)
\]
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, the following is *much* simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\genericmacro}{mE{_^}{{a+}{\alpha}}}{%
  \mathrm{#1}_{#2}^{#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\I}{}{\genericmacro{I}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\D}{}{\genericmacro{D}}

\begin{document}
\[
 \I x(t) \qquad \D x(t)
\]
\[
 \I_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t) \qquad \D_{b-}^{1-\alpha} x(t)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would define

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \math_sb:n { \c_math_subscript_token   { #1 } } % or, e.g., \math_subscript:n if you prefer
\cs_new_protected:Nn \math_sp:n { \c_math_superscript_token { #1 } } % or, e.g., \math_superscript:n if you prefer
\cs_new_protected:Nn \math_sbsp:nn { \math_sb:n { #1 } \math_sp:n { #2 } } % or \math_subsuperscript:n if you prefer or whatever
\cs_new_protected:Nn \math_sbsp:nnn { #1 \math_sbsp:nn { #2 } { #3 } } % for use in \math_sbsp:nnn { a } { b } { c } = a_b^c
```

And then use those inside expl3 context.

---

In your case, your problem is with `E{_^}`, you need to somehow input that `_` outside of `\ExplSyntax(On|Off)` so that it's not catcode letter. Here's one way of doing that, far from ideal.

```
\cs_new_protected:Nn \serafiel_definedelimiters:nNN
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand #2 {#1}
   {
    \math_sbsp:nnn { \mathrm{#3} } {##1} {##2} ##3
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \serafiel_definedelimiters:nNN { ncN }

\NewDocumentCommand \definedelimitersaux { O{mmm} m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \serafiel_definedelimiters:ncN { #1 } { ##1 } ##1
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand\definedelimiters{m}{\definedelimitersaux[E{_^}{{a+}{\alpha}}m]{#1}}

\definedelimiters{D, I}
```